# Editor breaks line within lstlisting

Tags: listings, line-breaking, lstlisting

I'm using an editor that breaks lines after a line length of 80 characters. Whenever I use a long `lstinline` at the end of a line and the editor continues in a new line I get the error message `Package Listings: lstinline ended by EOL.`

Consider following example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}

\lstset{
    breaklines=true,
    breakatwhitespace=true,
    language=c,
    basicstyle=\small\ttfamily,
    numbers=left,
    numberstyle=\tiny,
    frame=tb,
    keepspaces=true,
    columns=fullflexible,
    showstringspaces=false,
}
\begin{document}
This is a text with a long function in \lstinline|void some_func(int
some_argument)|, where the editor automatically adds a second line.
\end{document}
```

The editor automatically adds a new line after `void some_func(int` which results in the error message. Is there a way to span the `lstlisting` command over multiple lines?

Comment: Why don't you just put the \lstinline into a line by itself?  With certain exceptions (like verbatim and \lstinline) LaTeX converts newlines into spaces (and ignores extra spaces).

Comment: @JohnKormylo It's possible that a function name has more than 80 characters, so the editor would break lines anyways

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't find a key-value interface for this in `listings.sty`, so here's here's a hard coded method. You have to change the macro `\lst@InlineM`:

```
\def\lst@InlineM#1{\gdef\lst@inlinechars{%
    \lst@Def{`#1}{\lst@DeInit\egroup\global\let\lst@inlinechars\@empty}%
    \lst@Def{13}{\lst@DeInit\egroup \global\let\lst@inlinechars\@empty
        \PackageError{Listings}{lstinline ended by EOL}\@ehc}}% <--- Error message
    \lst@inlinechars}
```

to something that doesn't produce an error. The default behaviour is to end the `\lstinline` (with `\lst@DeInit\egroup`) then throw an error. To make the new line behave as a space you can do:

```
\def\lst@InlineM#1{\gdef\lst@inlinechars{%
    \lst@Def{`#1}{\lst@DeInit\egroup\global\let\lst@inlinechars\@empty}%
    \lst@Def{13}{\lst@ProcessSpace}}% <---
    \lst@inlinechars}
```

> [image]

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}

\lstset{
    breaklines=true,
    breakatwhitespace=true,
    language=c,
    basicstyle=\small\ttfamily,
    numbers=left,
    numberstyle=\tiny,
    frame=tb,
    keepspaces=true,
    columns=fullflexible,
    showstringspaces=false,
}

\makeatletter
\def\lst@InlineM#1{\gdef\lst@inlinechars{%
    \lst@Def{`#1}{\lst@DeInit\egroup\global\let\lst@inlinechars\@empty}%
    \lst@Def{13}{\lst@ProcessSpace}}%
    \lst@inlinechars}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
This is a text with a long function in \lstinline|void some_func(int
some_argument)|, where the editor automatically adds a second line.
\end{document}
```

Comment: Imho it is rather dangerous: If you forget the closing delimiter in the \lstinline it will eat up your document and you can get rather bewildering errors. I would change the input or the editor.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I completely agree. However many editors have a reasonable syntax highlighting which will make the mistake obvious. But if someone writes `\makeatletter` they should be willing to pay the price ;)